# Code works on the console but not on script

Tags: javascript, input, console, addeventlistener, keyup

My problem is that my code works on the console when setting a Breakpoint on a specific line but doesn't work when running the script or with a Breakpoint on any other line.

I have an input field with a keyup listener that fires even with pasted inputs, so I'm trying to develop a solution that recognizes pasted inputs and removes the keyup listener while doing so.

The code runs good in the console when I set a Breakpoint on the line that removes the keyup listener, but it doesn't work when I directly run the script on the page or with a Breakpoint on any other line. I tried 'DOMContentLoaded', window.load, checking "document.readyState", moving my variables and functions, but still nothing works.

```
//Recognizes pasted inputs and calls to remove "Keyup" listener

searchInput.onpaste = function remove() {keyupListener();};


//Removes "Keyup" listener

function keyupListener() {
//Here's where it works when I set a Breakpoint
   searchInput.removeEventListener('keyup', dynamicPagination); 
}

// Keyup listener

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
   dynamicPagination();
});

searchButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
   dynamicPagination();
});
```

The behavior of the code when it doesn't work is that it doesn't read the removeEventListener, and fires up the keyup handler with the pasted input.

I'm only interested in vanilla JS solutions.

Comment: To remove a specific event listener, you have to pass a reference to the *exact same function*, not a function similar to the existing handler. You're creating the event listeners with anonymous `=>` function wrappers.

Comment: You're right @Pointy. Thanks! But fixing that brings other problems with my code that is not in this snippet (I didn't want to overload the question). The answer Shashank  gave below is closer to solving my issue, but I have to clarify you were absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Recognizes pasted inputs and calls to remove "Keyup" listener

var pasted = false;
searchInput.onpaste = function() {pasted=true;};

// Keyup listener
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    if(!pasted) dynamicPagination();
});

searchButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
   if(!pasted) dynamicPagination();
});
//---------------------------------------------------------
Try the below code:- 
//---------------------------------------------------------
<textarea rows=5 cols=50 id=inpt></textarea><button id=btn>buttonn</button>
<div id=dv></div>
<script>
(function(){
var pasted = false;
var searchInput = document.getElementById('inpt');
searchInput.onpaste = function() {pasted=true;};

// Keyup listener
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    if(!pasted) dynamicPagination();
    dv.innerHTML += "<BR>pasted: " + (++dynCnt);
    pasted = false;
});

var searchButton = document.getElementById('btn');
searchButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
   if(!pasted) dynamicPagination();
   dv.innerHTML += "<BR>pasted= " + (++dynCnt);
   pasted = false;
});


var dv = document.getElementById('dv');
dv.innerHTML = "";
var dynCnt = 0;
function dynamicPagination() {
    dv.innerHTML += "<BR>dynamicPagination" + (++dynCnt);
}
})();
</script>
//---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This solution works, but I'd have to revert the ```pasted``` variable to ```false``` after the interpreter goes into the "keyup" handler, so the ```dynamicPagination``` function goes back into play while firing the "keyup" handler.

I add there an ```else if (pasted) pasted = false```, and I go back to the initial problem. The code works fine on the console, but not on the script. Any thoughts?

Comment: Even more weird. Sometimes it work, sometimes it doesn't. @shashank